# Will felony charges from 2004 (adjudication withheld) and 2005 (dropped) show up on a background check?

Tags: human-resources, background-check

I applied for a collections rep, working for a hospital in Florida. I was offered the job pending my background check. I have a felony on my record from 2004, grand theft with adjudication withheld. I also was arrested in 2005 for the same thing but the charges were dropped once I went to court. Could this show up on my background? its been 10 yrs for 1 arrest and 12 for the other one.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for [law.SE].

Answer (score 2):

> Could this show up on my background?

**Yes.** I am not in HR or law or even law enforcement, just a random person, but even so, for my county of residence, I am able to search by name through the county clerk's records. Information is available about both criminal and civil court cases.

For criminal cases, the results include arrest data and disposition of the case, as well as identifying information about the defendant such as full name, date of birth, race, sex, height/weight, and address, so I would be able to confirm whether it is you.

Civil cases include matters such as name changes, paternity suits, and divorces, but there is much less identifying information about the parties involved.

I have seen arrest records dating back to the 1970s in this database.

Other jurisdictions may vary, but for the question "could this show up", the answer is yes.